# Access a queue inside a built labview application .exe

Tags: labview

I have a built labview application .exe within which there is a labview queue. I would like to put items into this queue from a labview vi which exists outside of the application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible as, .exe has its own memory pool and it will not share its memory with LabVIEW vi.

Consider using network structures, such as NSP, or Network Streams or TCP/IP.

Comment: will try UDP messages. Thanks.

Comment: More generally -- communication with an EXE of LabVIEW is done the same way as communication with EXE of any language. You can't generally inject values into any EXE -- you need some sort of process-level communication. Pipes, localhost ports, etc., as noted by Khachik.